# FFmpeg drawtext limit on max number of open font files

Tags: ffmpeg, fonts, fontconfig

Using FFmpeg, I am trying to create a video from images on which I annotate/write text using `drawtext` (`filter_complex` is used).

If the number of `drawtext` filters exceeds 500, I get an error:

> Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans

FFmpeg apparently has a limit on the number of font-files that can be opened simultaneously.

1. How does `drawtext` work – why is a new file opened for each filter, even if all fonts files are same?
2. Any way to solve this issue? By increasing the limit on files that can be opened simultaneously?
3. `drawtext` documentation has an option `fontconfig` – how to use it? Is it helpful in the above scenario?

Complete command-
`ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -i input_audio.wav -y -r 10 -filter_complex_script filterCommand.txt -crf 22 -threads 2 -preset ultrafast output_video.mp4`
filterCommand.txt - text file contains `drawtext=enable='between(n,0,0)':fontsize=10:fontfile='C\:/‌​windows/Fonts/calibr‌​ib.ttf':fontcolor='0‌​x000000` comma separated - repeated 509 times
509 times drawtext works, 510 times drawtext fails.
Console logs-
`ffmpeg version N-81989-g7845c13 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 32.100 / 55. 32.100
  libavcodec     57. 61.103 / 57. 61.103
  libavformat    57. 52.100 / 57. 52.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 64.100 /  6. 64.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, concat, from 'temp/test4/node-5303540733531691237.txt':
  Duration: 00:00:01.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, wav, from 'temp/32_anonymoususer1825804750300631765/part/1_subPart/audio/part_audio.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:09.50, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_drawtext_509 @ 000000000a4ca9a0] Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000000000b8cfc0] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'enable=between(n,21,21):fontsize=10:fontfile=C\:/windows/Fonts/calibrib.ttf:fontcolor=0x000000:text=100\.0:x=398:y=119-th'
Error initializing complex filters.
No such file or directory`

Comment: Not too familiar with the inner workings of the filter, but can you please give us a command that exhibits the problem, and the full command-line output that you get as a result? (If it's too long, you can also upload to PasteBin.)

Comment: Sample command-`ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -i input_audio.wav -y -r 10 -vf "drawtext=enable='between(n,0,0)':fontsize=10:fontfile='C\:/windows/Fonts/calibrib.ttf':fontcolor='0x000000':text='120\.0':x=480:y=61-th" -crf 22 -threads 2 -preset ultrafast output_video.mp4` -  repeat the drawtext command for atleast 550 times

Comment: Please include everything as asked for, i.e. the whole command and its complete output, not just the one error.

Comment: [ffmpeg ticket 5893](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5983#no1) can be referred - it mentions about 512 drawtext filters, but no solution/remedy

Comment: I see, was about to guess that something like that would be the problem. I'm afraid all you can do is wait for someone to fix the bug. Not sure if it's that easy since each filter individually loads its fonts.